# Ruby on rails: can't convert String into Integer for if contition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a very simple code on erb page (Ruby on Rails). The error is strange: **can't convert String into Integer**

Code is very simple:)

```
<% if q['year'] %>
    q[YEAR]  <%= q['year'] %>
<% end %>
```

Any help?:) There is a lot such error described in internet but not exact like mine!

Comment: i think q['year'.to_i]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`q` is probably an instance of `Array`, not `Hash`, so `q.[]` method expects integer argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use debugger and verify the class of q. It doesn't seem to be a hash, so it can't be accessed through a string key. It looks like q is a string or an array.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to debug what you have in the view is to set a `debugger` like following:

```
<% debugger %>
```

Then you can evaluate expressions and see what is there. There are guides for debugging in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.8/debugging_rails_applications.html (rails 4) or http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/debugging_rails_applications.html (rails 3) or http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/debugging_rails_applications.html (rails 2)

Another thing you can do, far far away from using `debugger`, is to print out the variable using the `debug` helper:

```
<%= debug q %>
```

This will print a human readable version of whatever `q` contains.